# Problems loading the storage in the renderer for the combobox field

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

My field looks like this:

```
...

{
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            text: 'MyField',
            dataIndex: 'contragent',
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                allowBlank: false,
                displayField:'name',
                valueField:'id',
                queryMode:'remote',
                store: Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ContrAgents')
            },
            renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
                store_ca = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ContrAgents');             
                if (record.data.contragent != ''){
                    store_ca.load();
                    var contr = store_ca.getById(record.data.contragent);
                    //indexInStore = store_ca.findExact('id', value);
                    console.log(contr);
                    return contr.data.name;
                }
            }
        },

...
```

Store 'ContrAgents' looks like this:

```
Ext.define('BookApp.store.ContrAgents', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'BookApp.model.ContrAgents',
    autoLoad: true, 
    proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',            
            url: 'app/data/Contragents.json'            
        }
});
```

The problem is that the name of the required field is not returned (`contr.data.name`), `contr` is null.

Apparently the store does not have time to load, in this case I need to load it, but `store_ca.load ()` does not bring results.
How to load the store correctly to use

`store_ca.getById (record.data.contragent);` to return the name of the field?

Comment: Store loading is asynchronous.

Comment: @Evan Trimboli How exactly to load store asynchronously? Give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you would need to use a store to populate the value in the grid's cell, because you could always just send the text value through the grid's store as opposed to the id.

You probably have a good reason for doing it, so I've revisited the fiddle and implemented it accordingly. You should be able to check it out [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mnf)

**The changes**

*../app/store/ContrAgents.js*

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.store.ContrAgents', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Fiddle.model.ContrAgents',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'Contragents.json'
    }
});
```

*../app/store/ListViewStore.js*

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.store.ListViewStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Fiddle.model.ListViewModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'List.json'
    }
});
```

*../app/view/ListView.js*

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.ListView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.booklist',
    itemId: 'BookList',
    store: 'ListViewStore',
    xtype: 'listview',
    plugins: 'gridfilters',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        // Pin an instance of the store on this grid
        me.myContrAgents = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ContrAgents');

        // Manually load the 'ContrAgents' first
        me.myContrAgents.load(function(records, operation, success) {
            // Now load the 'ListViewStore' store
            me.getStore().load();
        });

        me.columns = [
            {
                header: 'ID',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                sortable: true,
                width: 35
            },
            {
                text: 'Контрагент',
                dataIndex: 'contragent',
                renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
                    if (value > 0) {
                        if (rec = me.myContrAgents.findRecord('id', value)) {
                            return rec.get('name');
                        }
                    }
                    return '';
                }
            }
        ];
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

*Data/List.json*

```
"data" : [
    {"id": 1, "contragent": "2"},
    {"id": 2, "contragent": "3"},
    {"id": 3, "contragent": "4"} 
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot, your answer is correct.Hendrik, I don’t have a good reason to use store to populate the value in the grid’s cell. I'm new to extjs and it seems to me that the right decision is to load the store first, and then get the name records by id. How can I just send the text value through the grid's store as opposed to the id?

Comment: I'm assuming that both resources are available in the same source (database/service/etc). Therefore, you can always populate the grid's store with the data you want to display. See my updated fiddle that shows this (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mof)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to query the store before it's data is actually populated. You want to avoid loading the store for each time the renderer event is triggered.

**The Ext.data.Store->load function is asynchronous**

See [docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load)

```
store.load({
    scope: this,
    callback: function(records, operation, success) {
        // the operation object
        // contains all of the details of the load operation
        console.log(records);
    }
});
```

Change your implementation to this and test if it works

```
renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
    store_ca = Ext.data.StoreManager.get('ContrAgents');             
    if (record.data.contragent != ''){
        store_ca.load(function(records, operation, success) {
            console.log('loaded records');
            var contr = store_ca.getById(record.data.contragent);
            indexInStore = store_ca.findExact('id', value);
            console.log({
                contr: contr,
                indexInStore: indexInStore
            });
        });

        // Not sure what you are trying to return here
        // return contr.data.name;
    }
}
```

**Remote Combo in ExtJS Grid Example**

I found a good example for what you are trying to accomplish here with a combo dropdown in a grid with a remote store, check out [this post](https://extjs.eu/ext-examples/#combo-in-grid) (you might have to register for free but the solution is worth it and I won't plagiarise it here)

**Grid with combo edit widget with binding**

Perhaps this could help...

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.view.ListView' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.booklist',
    itemId: 'BookList',
    store: 'ListViewStore',
    xtype: 'listview',
    plugins: ['cellediting','gridfilters'],


    initComponent: function() {
        this.columns = [
            {
                header: 'ID',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                sortable: true,
                width: 35
            },
            {
                text: 'Контрагент',
                width: 150,
                xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'contragent',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'combo',
                    bind: '{record.contragent}',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'id',
                    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('ContrAgents')
                }
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Changed your code on your recommendation. The console now displays:`loaded records
Object { contr: Object, indexInStore: -1 }` . Added Store definition to your question

Comment: The article is displayed incompletely even after free registration and does not allow me to understand the implementation of this combobox. I played part of my application in [FIDDLE ](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2mku)

Comment: @Ambasador, have you tried the updated solution yet?

Comment: Thank. Yes, I tried to apply your new recommendation and it works, but I do not need to select a value from the combobox just the display